# Bypass login page in auth0 to run e2e tests with Jest & Puppeteer

Tags: jwt, jestjs, integration-testing, auth0, puppeteer

I have a React/Node web app that utilizes Auth0 for user authentication.  I have set up Puppeteer to hit `localhost:3000`, which keeps redirecting me to the login page when I want to test my app because I don't have a JWT (or `access_token`). In addition, my auth0 is set up to have MFA, in which after this step will provide me my JWT.

In other words, before I hit my web app, I will always hit the login page asking for email/password, then will be given an SMS to verify through MFA (multi-factor authentication). Only afterwards will be redirected to the webapp with a token. I just want to enter and test my web app, not Auth0.

In my first attempt, I tried creating a . `grant_type` of `client_credentials` and hitting this url: `https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/oauth/token` but I get nothing relevant back.

A second solution I thought of was updating the Rules in my Auth0 dashboard to check for a particular test email and skip MFA, but it feels risky and likely to break the existing login function. This was set up by another developer and I don't feel safe touching it.

Is it possible to run another server with a way to mock Auth0's service? So before any of my tests, I have some sort of mock-JWT that will verify me in my app's server and store the mock-JWT in the Chromium browser as `localStorage`? Something like...

```
test('Navigate to Endpoint auth page', async () => {
  // Run mock server that mock's Auth0 service
  // Store mock-JWT in Chromium's browser like so:
  // await page.evaluate(()=> localStorage.setItem('mockJWT'));

  page = await global.__BROWSER__.newPage();
  await page.goto('localhost:3000', { waitUntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded'] });
```

I'm not sure how to approach this or what else to try. If anyone has any idea or spare time, anything would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: not sure how you would do that in puppeteer, but if you were doing a unit test, you could use an http interceptor like nock and return whatever response you want.  I think i remember wdio or cypress supporting similar behavior, but anyway, i think you're on the right track.

Comment: I would setup a private test user account which you can give to puppeteer and have it go that way. Or change the authorize to accept a temporary token that'll allow you to login and make requests.